# How to throw custom object as Error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I'm extending Error object here and passing the status code, code and the message.

```
class AuthenticationException extends Error {
constructor(statusCode, code, message) {
super();
this.statusCode = statusCode;
this.message = message;
this.code = code;
}
}
export default AuthenticationException;
```

But the Error throws only like below

```
{
"error": "Unable to decode token"
}
```

But this is not what i was looking for. The result should be like,

```
{
"message": "Unable to decode token",
"code":1234
}
```

Please help me If you can. And can I get many key-value pair as throw exception?

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that the call to `super()` throws before the assignments run. But since `super()` needs to be called before accessing `this`, you may be out of luck.

Even if you could skip `super()`, you'd need to find a way of telling the `Error` class to print not only `message` but also `code` and `statusCode`.

What you're trying to do can be achieved by just throwing the object you need:

```js
throw { message: '...', code: '...', statusCode: '...' }
```

Or, if you use this in a bunch of places and don't want to keep typing out the object, use a function:

```js
let customThrow = (message, code, statusCode) => {
  throw { message, code, statusCode };
}
```

There's no need for classes, let alone inheritance. Much simpler this way.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Are there any other ways where I can throw an error like a JSON object?

Comment: This object will be in the console right?. But I want to get it to the window as a json response

Comment: Yes. What do you mean by "to the window"?

Comment: I got it buddy. Thanks:)

Comment: Ok but can you still explain what you meant so I know?

Answer (score 1):

You can't throw an object as an error. The `Error` constructor doesn't support that. Another approach is to have the custom object in a separate property. You can get that custom object out in the `catch` block:

```js
export type ApiError = {
  statusCode: number;
  code: number;
};

export class AuthenticationException extends Error {
  public apiError: ApiError;

  constructor(message: string, apiError: ApiError, options?: ErrorOptions) {
    super(message, options);

    this.apiError = apiError;
    this.message = message;
  }
}

try {
  throw new AuthenticationException('Unable to decode token', {
    code: 1234,
    statusCode: 401,
  });
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof AuthenticationException) {
    console.log(e.message);
    console.log(e.apiError);
  }
}
```

**Console output:**

```
Unable to decode token
{
  "code": 1234,
  "statusCode": 401
}
```

**Reference:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#custom_error_types